# Restore Sonar Quality profile returns HTTP 400 error

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to upgrade to latest sonar Qube release 4.3.2.

Followed the steps given in [link](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading)

After server started successfully, I am trying to restore the quality profile.
But When I clicking on Restore profile I am getting HTTP 400 error.

```
This error (HTTP 400 Bad Request) means that Internet Explorer was able to connect to the web server, but the webpage could not be found because of a problem with the address.
```

And when I am trying to create a new profile, I am getting error

```
 SonarQube (404) The page you were looking for doesn't exist.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you attach to this thread the content of your log/sonar.log file ?

Comment: @Freddy, Due to size limit on SO, I can't copy all the logs. Please share your email ID.